# Convolution of Distributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am working on a rather brief introduction to distributions and I am quite stuck on the section on convolution. I have two questions in particular:

The convolution of a distribution $u$ and a compactly supported smooth function $v$ is defined as $u(v_x)$, where $v_x(y) = v(x-y)$. It is clear that this is a function, but, to me at least, it is not clear why it is smooth. I have seen one proof which uses Taylor's theorem with remainder, but is there another way to show this?

Secondly, is $u$ is a distribution and $v, \phi$ are compactly supported smooth functions, then why do we have 
$\int u*v(x)\phi(x)dx = u(\tilde{v}*\phi), $ where $\tilde{v}(x)=v(-x)$?

I am obviously new to this, so any good references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a test function $\varphi \in D(\mathbb{R})$ and a distribution $ T \in D'(\mathbb{R})$ let $$ \phi(x) = T \ast \varphi(x)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty T(y) \varphi(x-y)dy$$ Claim : for every $k$, $\phi^{(k)}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty T(y) \varphi^{(k)}(x-y)dy$ is well-defined. Thus $\phi \in C^\infty$

$\qquad $ (note $\varphi^{(k)}(x+\epsilon-.)-\varphi^{(k)}(x-.) \to 0$ in the test function topology)

Therefore if $T$ is a compactly supported distribution then $T \ast \varphi$ is a test function and we can define $S \ast T \ast \varphi = S \ast (T \ast \varphi)$  for any distribution $S$. Moroever if $S$ is compactly supported then the convolution is commutative $S \ast T = T \ast S$.

Your last point follows from $\int_{-\infty}^\infty U(y) \varphi(y)dy = (U \ast \varphi(-.))(0)$

Comment: Why are you able to write down T(y)? Isn't it a distribution, not a function?

Comment: @D.Hudson You can write it $T(\psi(x-.))$ if you prefer, this is just a notation (it is not the Riemann nor the Lebesgue integral) but as you see it is insightful. And thanks to the convolution you can define $T(\psi)$ as a limit of Riemann integrals.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So I guess I should refine my question. Why does $\epsilon^{-1}[\phi(x-\epsilon-.)-\phi(x-.)]$ converge uniformly?

Comment: @D.Hudson $\psi_a(y) = \frac{\phi(y+a)-\phi(y)}{a} = \frac{1}{a}\int_y^{y+a} \phi'(y)dy$ and $\lim_{a \to 0} \psi_a =  \phi'$ in the test function space (whose topology is the uniform convergence of all derivatives, on a compact support). Otherwise let $\psi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x T(\phi'(y-.)dy$ seen as a limit of Riemann sums, those are finite sums so you can exchange $T$ and $\sum$ to obtain $\psi(x) = T(\int_{-\infty}^x \phi'(y-.)dy)=T (\phi(x-.))$   hence $T(\phi(x-.))$ is $C^1$

Comment: It is clear now! Thank you @reuns.